# MediaCodec adaptive playback Failed to get port format error

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, decoder

I am rendering a video stream using MediaCodec which I initialize at first with MediaFormat. Then I parse SPS and PPS when available and send them to the inputbuffers to re-configure mid-stream. Seems to work except before receiving output format changed I get these errors:

```
2021-01-20 17:36:18.731 13553-13628/com.test.client E/ACodec: Wrong cropped rect (0, 0, 1280, 720) vs. frame (864, 480)
2021-01-20 17:36:18.731 13553-13628/com.test.client E/ACodec: [OMX.amlogic.avc.decoder.awesome.secure] Failed to get port format to send format change
```

The resolution seems to actually change, but outputformatchanged is returning the old format for some reason. Any idea what I need to do?